# Typo3 : datetime +2 hour gap issue

Tags: typo3

I have an extension to create events and I can set hours for the start and end of the event.

When I display my hours, there is a gap of +2 hour. When I set 10:00, it display 12:00 .

there is my debug :

[image: debug hour]

I display it like that, and I found a temporary but ugly solution by adding "-2 hours" :

```
 <div class="date mb-4 mb-md-0">
      <f:format.date format="%d %B %Y">{atelier.date}</f:format.date>
      <f:format.date format="H:i" base="{atelier.heuredebut}">-2 hours</f:format.date>
                                -
      <f:format.date format="H:i" base="{atelier.heurefin}">-2 hours</f:format.date>
 </div>
```

If it can help, there is my model :

```
    protected $heuredebut;
    
/**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getHeuredebut()
    {
        return $this->heuredebut;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $heuredebut
     */
    public function setHeuredebut($heuredebut)
    {
        $this->heuredebut = $heuredebut;
    }
```

and my TCA :

```
        'heuredebut' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:reservationatelier/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_reservationatelier_domain_model_atelier.heuredebut',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'dbType' => 'time',
                'eval' => 'time, int, null',
            ],
        ],
```

I checked my settings of my server and my php version, everything was ok.
So that's not the problem, do you have any idea where it could be?
thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configuration variable [`$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘SYS’][‘phpTimeZone’]`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/SYS.html#globals-typo3-conf-vars-sys-phptimezone). Start-/Stoptime are calculated based on this timezone.

For instances hosted/maintained in Germany it's `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘SYS’][‘phpTimeZone’] = 'Europe/Berlin'` (winter: UTC/GMT +1, summer: UTC/GMT +2).